# Creative not showing

Tags: prebid.js

I'm integrating prebid.js with DFP, however after added a new creative using the code on this[guide](http://prebid.org/adops/step-by-step.html), the creative is not showing.

The code I've take from the page looks like this:

```
<script>
var w = window;
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  w = w.parent;
  if (w.pbjs) {
    try {
      w.pbjs.renderAd(document, '%%PATTERN:hb_adid%%');
      break;
    } catch (e) {
      continue;
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

P/S: I've been waited for hours but still no changes.

Answer (score 0):

Only after the prebid line item wins you would be able to see the creative render on the page. Are you seeing the prebid line items winning when you debug admanager delivery?